# What are the advantages of using onClick in React components over jQuery's .on("click") method?

Tags: jquery, reactjs

Recently I've been working on a task management project with dependencies that include both React and jQuery.  Users can view a daily list of dynamically-added tasks, which are either loaded from a remote server via AJAX or created by the user via a "new task" control.  The list of tasks is rendered into a parent `<section>` element that exists within an HTML page.

Here are some possible actions that a user can take on a task:

- Edit the task's description
- Add notes regarding actions taken on the task
- Mark the task as completed
- Re-schedule the task to a new due date

Each action is initiated by clicking its corresponding `<button>` element.  When performing these actions, users can either confirm their action to commit the change or cancel and revert to the original state of the task.  These confirm and cancel controls are also triggered by clicking buttons.

All in all, each task contains as many as 12 button controls, and thus adds 12 click event bindings.  I know I can write functions within my React component classes that will perform the action, and that I can call these functions with React by including an `onClick` attribute in the `<button>` element of my render functions:

```
var AddNoteConfirm = React.createClass({
    handleClick: function() {
        // logic to save the added note...
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <button className="addNote-confirm" onClick={this.handleClick}>
                Save Note
            </button>
        );
    }
});
```

But let's say I'm rendering 50 tasks at once.  That would create **600** event bindings.

Using the `.on()` method of jQuery I would only need to perform **12** event bindings, because I can bind to the parent `<section>` container and pass a selector for a given button as an argument:

```
$('#task-container').on('click', '.addNote-confirm', function() {
    // logic to save the added note...
});
```

As the number of event handlers is greatly reduced with this strategy, wouldn't the jQuery implementation of event handling be the better, more scalable option?  Or perhaps I'm overlooking something.  Are there other reasons why the React implementation would be the better solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

React uses event delegation (like `jquery.on()`) in it's Synthetic Events system for the same performance issues - see [Under the Hood: Autobinding and Event Delegation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#under-the-hood-autobinding-and-event-delegation).

In addition the event system is an integral part of a react component. If you'll use outside event, you'll have to somehow connect it to the current component to use `.setState` or call a callback that came from the component's parent via `props`.

Comment: I'd say I was *definitely* overlooking something, namely that portion of the React documentation.  :)  Thanks for your answer!